# Update a single row in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I am having trouble with a really simple SQL statement: `UPDATE`.

I would only like to update the booking_date column in a specific row.

Here is the statement I'm using:

```
UPDATE `coupon-codes` SET `booking_id`=:timestamp WHERE `id` = :id
```

I'm using PDO named placeholders.

I always get an incorrect syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I tried without backticks:

```
UPDATE coupon-codes SET booking_id = :timestamp WHERE id = :id
```

Still doesn't work.

Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image]

Edit 2:

Here is the error message I'm getting when using backticks:
[image]

Edit 3:

For reference, here is an `INSERT` statement I used before, which works without any problems:

```
INSERT INTO `coupon-codes` (`code`, `date`) VALUES (:code, :date)
```

Edit 4:

Sorry, wrongly said some things in the comments, to clarify, see this:

I am using BACKTICKS everywhere. This is the query that doesnt work:

```
UPDATE `coupon-codes` SET `booking_date`=:timestamp WHERE `id` = :id
```

I also had a typo in the original question which had booking_id instead of booking_date field, but that doesn't matter, since I'm getting a SYNTAX ERROR.

Here is the PHP code I'm trying to run it with:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `coupon-codes` SET `booking_date`=:timestamp WHERE `id` = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $time);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Aramillo I also tried to remove the quotes. See edit in the question.

Comment: The first version with backticks was correct. `coupon-codes` would be seen as two fields being subtracted, e.g. `field1 MINUS field2`. There's nothing wrong with the first query as-written.

Comment: @MarcB I edited the question again, now with another error message I'm getting WHEN using quotes.

Comment: @Aramillo The table name is correct, I've used many SELECT and INSERT queries before. Only UPDATE isnt working for some strange reason

Comment: and please get the terminology correct. "quotes" means `'` or `"`. You're using backticks. (`\``).

Comment: @MarcB I'm using backticks for the table name, and quotes for the field. See edit for a previous INSERT statement I used that works.

Comment: you have to use backticks EVERYWHERE. usign quotes turns things into strings. `select 'foo' from `... is selecting a word "foo". ``select `foo` from`` is selecting a FIELD named 'foo'.

Comment: Sorry, said it wrong. I'm using BACKTICKS everywhere, as in the first version of the question. Backticks for table name and field names.

Comment: Just a guess: Could you try to put a space between the `=` and the `:`, i. e. use `= :`?

Answer (score 0):

Basic MySQL syntax:

```
'foo' - single-quotes. turns the quote word into a string literal
`foo` - backticks. used to escape table/fieldnames that happen to be reserved words


SELECT 'select' FROM ... -- select the literal word "select" from some table
SELECT `select` FROM ... -- select the field NAMED "select" from some table
SELECT select FROM ...   -- syntax error - using a reserved word "select"
```

Given your error messages, you probably have one of the following:

```
UPDATE 'coupon-code' ...   -- can't update a string. must specify a table name
UPDATE coupon-code ...  -- math operation: coupon MINUS code - not a table name
```

Comment: Is this PDO or mysqli code you've written? Only PDO supports named placeholders. mysqli only supports `?` anonymous placeholders

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Predefined Constants (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php);

Example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `coupon-codes` SET `booking_date`=:timestamp WHERE `id` = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```